# Blazor InputDate not updating UI upon force change

Tags: c#, blazor, components, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I'm using the built in ASPNETCORE.Component.Forms InputDate but when selecting a date it does not override the UI when assigning another value it's always the selectedDate.

```
<InputDate ValueExpression="@(()=>MyModel.TestDate)"
                                   Value="MyModel.TestDate"
                                   ValueChanged="@((DateTime value) => CheckDate(value))"/>

private void CheckDate(DateTime selectedDate)
        {
            if (selectedDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                MyModel.TestDate = selectedDate;
            }
            else
            {
                MyModel.TestDate = DateTime.Now; // Issue here UI does not updates
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }
```

using WebAssembly 5.0.7

Comment: Are you using InputDate in an EditForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult one to explain.

Starting point: The current displayed value is today, *7-Sep-2023*.

1. When you change the data in the input to *8-Sep-2023* the new value gets passed back to `InputDate` though the `OnChange` event. At this point `Value` in `InputDate` is *7-Sep-2023*: there's a data inconsistency.  `MyModel.TestDate` is also set to *7-Sep-2023*, and the value held in the Renderer's `ParameterView` is *7-Sep-2023*.
2. In your `CheckDate` code the new value is out of range, so you set `MyModel.TestDate` to *7-Sep-2023*.  You don't need to, it's still *7-Sep-2023*: you haven't changed it.
3. When the parent component renders, the value hasn't changed so *7-Sep-2023* is passed into the component as `Value`.  `InputDate` will always render in the cascade as `ValueExpression` and `ValueExpression` are objects:  as reference types the Renderer can't be sure if they have changed, so it renders anyway.
4. `InputDate` still believes the value is *7-Sep-2023*.  Remember the data inconsistency in the first paragraph.
5. **Important bit** The virtual DOM also believes it's *7-Sep-2023*, so the diffing process doesn't see a change, and therefore doesn't refresh the raw input [which is actually at *8-Sep-2023*]. It stays on the new value.

The way to solve this dilemma is:

1. Let the `MyModel.TestDate` get set to the new value
2. Yield with `await Task.Delay(1)` which allows a render to reset the values to the new one in the render chain.
3. Set the value to the validated value.
4. Let the final UI event render [when the UI event completes] handle the update.

Here's some demo code showing two ways to wire this up.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputDate class="mb-3" ValueExpression="@(()=>MyModel.TestDate)"
           Value="MyModel.TestDate"
           ValueChanged="@((DateTime value) => CheckDate(value))" />

<InputDate class="form-control mb-3" @bind-Value="this.MyModel.TestDate1" @bind-Value:after="this.ValidateDate" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-2">
    <pre>Date : @MyModel.TestDate.ToShortDateString()</pre>
    <pre>Date1 : @MyModel.TestDate1.ToShortDateString()</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Model MyModel = new();

    private async Task ValidateDate()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        if (MyModel.TestDate1 >= DateTime.Now)
            MyModel.TestDate1 = DateTime.Now; // Issue here UI does not updates
    }

    private async Task CheckDate(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        MyModel.TestDate = selectedDate;
        await Task.Delay(1);

        if (selectedDate >= DateTime.Now)
            MyModel.TestDate = DateTime.Now; // Issue here UI does not updates
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime TestDate1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, your explanation makes sense. OP stated he's using WebAssembly 5.0.7 so the second `InputDate` option you suggested `@bind-Value:after` wouldn't be valid, however the first option works as expected.

Comment: @Rbee - I added both in as others will come to this question in the future using the newer versions.  I aways try and consider that when providing an answer.

Comment: Alright, anyways I like your answer especially the breakdown of the the behaviour.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis there's one issue, when I input(type) 11/31/2024 which is invalid date, since it's later than today the component renders back to current date which is correct but still show as invalid date (has red error lines). if its 2/31/2024 no problem the issue occurs only when you have two digit months like 11 maybe because valuechanged already run on the first digit 1 thoughtss?

Comment: Hi - "but still show as invalid date (has red error lines)."  Where's that coming from?  Just checked my code and it doesn't show any red.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis here's the logic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222115/blazor-input-date-does-not-revalidate-upon-value-assignment)

Comment: Hi Yzak - Can you ask this as a new question.  I'm travelling  It's much easier to deal with, and others can contribute.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is causing this behaviour however, i'm answering to provide a solution for when `InputDate` is within an `EditForm`.

**Edit:** Refer to [@MrC's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061000/11779494) for an explanation of this behaviour.

#### When `InputDate` is in an `EditForm`

You can use the `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged` method to notify the EditContext that the field has changed.

[NotifyFieldChanged being called Snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mxOtYBle57iALfwk59)

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    <InputDate ValueExpression="@(()=>MyModel.TestDate)"
               Value="MyModel.TestDate"
               ValueChanged="@((DateTime value) => CheckDate(value))"/>
</EditForm>
@code{
    MyClass MyModel;
    EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyModel = new(){TestDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)};
        _editContext = new EditContext(MyModel);
    }

    private void CheckDate(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        if (selectedDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            MyModel.TestDate = selectedDate;
        }
        else
        {
            MyModel.TestDate = DateTime.Now;
            _editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => MyModel.TestDate));
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public DateTime TestDate {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Just creating a `FieldIdentifier` seems to do the trick, then the NotifyFieldChanged method does not need to be called manually.

[Creating Field Identifier snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QHOZEBFT33ZMMGlt24)

```
MyClass MyModel;
EditContext _editContext;
FieldIdentifier _testDateId;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyModel = new(){TestDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)};
    _editContext = new EditContext(MyModel);
    _testDateId = FieldIdentifier.Create(() => MyModel.TestDate);
}

private void CheckDate(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    MyModel.TestDate = selectedDate < DateTime.Now ? selectedDate : DateTime.Now;
}
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime TestDate {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: see my answer for a commentary on what's actually going on.  It happens in many controls when you try and set them back to the old value as some sort of validation process.